# SplitView application like Mail application of iPad

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

Hi i am very new in the iPhone/iPad technology i want to built an Navigation based application like Built in iPad mail application ? can any one give me sample code for this??

I want to Navigation but i am unable to understand this how to use.

RootViewController (Left-Side-Controller of SplitView)  and clicking on row i just want to push new NewTableView (2nd) and from NewTableView on clicking of row i want changes in DetailView (Rifht-Side-Controller of SplitView).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess its been a long time... but nevertheless check out the sample code from Apple [MultipleDetailView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775). It will provide you with what you want exactly.